Location selection after TDoA multi area solution
In TDoA multi region scenes, it is necessary to select the calculation result of the most suitable region to ensure a smooth transition of the label during motion, especially during region transitions, such as walking from region A to region B, and smoothly passing through the AB boundary without jumping back and forth.
I have tried using the RSSI of the base station in the arrival time of the tag to calculate the average RSSI of all base stations in the area, and then selecting the cells that are greater than the average as the settlement cells. Using this method may result in severe occlusion or filtering anomalies in some other situations, causing the calculated position to not correspond to the actual position;
We also attempted to calculate all regions that meet the solution conditions, convert the measurement time difference of the corresponding region into distance difference, and calculate the residual based on the settlement result and base station coordinates. Then, we selected the calculation result with the smallest residual among all regions that meet the solution conditions as the final result.
I hope the final filtering result can make the entire motion trajectory of the label smooth, especially in the transition of regions, which can better reflect the smoothness of motion.
My implementation is using Java, and some of the code is as follows：
 public void filterCalculate(String tagSn, int tagCalIndex, GroupCacheV2 cache) {
        Map<String, List<TagTimeData>> tagTimes = cache.getCache().getTagTime(tagSn, tagCalIndex);

        if (tagTimes.isEmpty()) return;
        tagTimes.values().removeIf(list -> list.size() <= 2);
        if (tagTimes.isEmpty()) return;
//        log.info("tagTimes: " + tagTimes);

        Map<String, double[]> resMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Double> residualMap = new HashMap<>();

        tagTimes.forEach((masterSn, tagTimeList) -> {
            int syncIndex = tagTimeList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tagTimeData -> tagTimeData.getTagTime().getSyncIndex()))
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .orElse(-1);
            if (syncIndex == -1) return;
            TDoAResult res = calculate(tagSn, syncIndex, masterSn, cache.getBaseStations().get(masterSn), tagTimeList, cache);
            if (res != null) {
                log.info("tagSn: " + tagSn + ", masterSn: " + masterSn + ", syncIndex: " + syncIndex + ", res: " + res);
                double residual = res.getResidual();
                residualMap.put(masterSn, residual);
                resMap.put(masterSn, res.getPosition());
            }
        });

        double[] selectRes;
        String masterSn;
//        if (!lastPosCache.containsKey(tagSn) || lastPosCache.get(tagSn) == null) {
//            masterSn = selectResidual(residualMap);
//            selectRes = masterSn == null ? null : resMap.get(masterSn);
//        } else {
//            double[] lastPos = lastPosCache.get(tagSn);
//
//            Map<String, double[]> filteredPosMap = new HashMap<>(resMap);
//            filteredPosMap.forEach((masterId, pos) -> {
//                double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos[0] - lastPos[0], 2) + Math.pow(pos[1] - lastPos[1], 2));
//                if (distance > 5) {
//                    filteredPosMap.remove(masterId);
//                    tagTimes.remove(masterId);
//                }
//            });
//            if (filteredPosMap.size() == 1) {
//                masterSn = filteredPosMap.keySet().iterator().next();
//                selectRes = filteredPosMap.get(masterSn);
//            } else if (filteredPosMap.size() > 1) {
//                masterSn = selectResidual(residualMap);
//                selectRes = masterSn == null ? null : filteredPosMap.get(masterSn);
//            }
//            masterSn = selectBestCell(tagTimes);
//            selectRes = masterSn == null ? null : resMap.get(masterSn);
//        }
        masterSn = selectResidual(residualMap);
        selectRes = masterSn == null ? null : resMap.get(masterSn);

        double[] finalRes = (selectRes != null) ?
                calMap.computeIfAbsent(tagSn, k -> new ChanTaylorKalmanTDOA()).ekfFun(new double[]{selectRes[0], selectRes[1]}) :
                calMap.computeIfAbsent(tagSn, k -> new ChanTaylorKalmanTDOA()).localization();
        lastPosCache.put(tagSn, finalRes);
        log.info("标签{}选择区域{}定位结果：{}", tagSn, masterSn, finalRes);
        if (masterSn != null && selectRes != null) {
            deviceHolder.getIfPresent(masterSn, (device, fence) -> {
                deviceService.addLocationData(device, finalRes, tagSn, fence.getFiltUnboundCard());
            });
        }
    }
private String selectResidual(Map<String, Double> residualMap) {
        return residualMap.entrySet().stream()
                .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
    }

private double calculateResidual(double[][] apLoc, double[] t, double[] pos, int masterIndex) {
        try {
            double[] t1 = IntStream.range(0, t.length).filter(i -> i != masterIndex).mapToDouble(i -> t[i]).toArray();
            double[] dist = Arrays.stream(t1).map(tt -> tt * T).toArray();
            double residual = 0;
//            double masterDist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos[0] - apLoc[0][0], 2) + Math.pow(pos[1] - apLoc[0][1], 2) + Math.pow(pos[2] - apLoc[0][2], 2));
            double masterDist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos[0] - apLoc[0][0], 2) +
                                          Math.pow(pos[1] - apLoc[0][1], 2));
            for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
//                double distCalculated = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos[0] - apLoc[i][0], 2) + Math.pow(pos[1] - apLoc[i][1], 2) + Math.pow(pos[2] - apLoc[i][2], 2)) - masterDist;
                double distCalculated = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos[0] - apLoc[i][0], 2) +
                                                  Math.pow(pos[1] - apLoc[i][1], 2))
                                        - masterDist;
                residual += Math.pow(dist[i] - distCalculated, 2);
            }
            return Math.sqrt(residual / t1.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("calculate residual error: " + e);
            return Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

